# Loop through Observable's List of objects without using subscribe

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java

I have an `Observable` object as follows

```
Observable<List<User>> observableUser = object.someMthodReturningObservable();
```

I want to loop though the `observableUser`, so I figured following code

1st Way:

```
observableUser.map(object ->{
            List<User> list = object;
            for(User user: list){
                Employee employee= new Employee();
                employee.setName(user.getName());
            }
            return null;
        });
```

2nd Way:

```
observableUser.flatMap(Observable::from).subscribe(object -> {
            User user = (User)object;
            Employee employee= new Employee();
            employee.setName(user.getName());
         });
```

Is there any way to loop through the List without using `subscribe` and `for` loop i.e using only `flatMap` or `map` functionalities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace nested loop with Java 8 flatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678892/replace-nested-loop-with-java-8-flatmap)

Comment: do operations `inside` flatMap. 
`user.flatMap(observableList -> observableList.flatMap(....`